# Source line length limit

Tags: c++, c++11, standards

What's the maximum length of a source line *all* compilers are *required to* accept? Did it change in C++11? If so, what was the old value?

I'm asking this question because I'm doing some heavy preprocessor voodoo (unfortunately, templates won't cut it), and doing so has a tendency to make the lines big very quickly. I want to stay on the safe side, so I won't have to worry about the possibility of compiler X on platform Y rejecting my code because of too long lines.

Comment: I would rather check whether there is a way the avoid preprocessor voodoo. That is more likely than to depend on an implementation detail

Comment: I wouldn't think it would be hard to make a C++ compiler accept infinite line lengths, but then I've never written one.

Comment: @stefanbachert: I can't avoid it, that's the problem. Also, the point of the question is to know where the implementation-defined land begins, so that I can avoid wandering into it.

Comment: @Fanael, it might be worth explaining if you haven't asked around already.

Comment: @MarkRansom: sure, but there's the standard, and there are implementations. The question is about the former.

Comment: Since I had to look this up, +1.

Comment: @Mark Ransom I think it would be impossible to make a C++ compiler accept infinite line lenghths, but I will never know for sure b/c my puny computer only stores finite source files.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

C++2003, **Annex B, (informative)
Implementation quantities** (sorry, don't have C++2011 handy)

> 2) The limits may constrain quantities that include those described below or others. The bracketed number
>   following each quantity is recommended as the minimum for that quantity. However, these quantities are
>   only guidelines and do not determine compliance.
>
> …
>
> - Characters in one logical source line [65 536].

You didn't ask about these, but they might be useful, also:

> - Nesting levels of parenthesized expressions within a full expression [256].
> - Macro identifiers simultaneously defined in one translation unit [65 536].
> - Arguments in one macro invocation [256].
> - Number of characters in an internal identifier or macro name [1 024].
> - Macro identifiers simultaneously defined in one translation unit [65 536].
> - Parameters in one macro definition [256].

---

*Postscript*: It is worth noting what "one logical source line" is. A *logical source line* is what you have **after**:

> - Physical source file characters are mapped to the basic source
>     character set
> - Trigraph
>     sequences (2.3) are replaced by corresponding single-character internal representations
> - Each instance of a new-line character and an immediately preceding backslash character is deleted

The logical source line is what you have **before**:

> - The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens
> - Preprocessing directives are executed and macro invocations are expanded.

[quotes from *C++ 2003, 2.1 **Phases of Translation***]

So, if the OP's concern is that the macros expand to beyond a reasonable line length, my answer is irrelevant. If the OP's concern is that his source code (after dealing with `\`, `\n`) might be too long, my answer stands.

Comment: Just to confirm, this is same in C++11.

Comment: +1:  It is the samne in C++11:  "— Characters in one logical source line [65 536]."  Annex B.2

Comment: Just to say it: A compiler is allowed to reject (or do anything else) a file containing the usual "hello world" code because of too long lines. That's undefined behavior then. I wonder why you have no clear statement in your answer about the consequences of violating the "long lines" limit...

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb:  Thanks for your reply.  I had involved myself in a C++ conversation today, a conversation that eventually degenerated into mockery of Linus Torvalds (who, as you know, does not care for C++).  To involve you was a mistake.  Sorry.  If you want to know, though, I was referring to when you said that you disliked unit testing.