# Long length lines in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, long-lines

I've previously read that a line length in C++ source code files are limited means longer than a size couldn't be compiled. true yes?
as you know in Qt creator many lines become long because of using Qt features, forexample for writing a string within a label it might be so long. so what will happen if our line became so long. Is it okay or some tricks should be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519738/source-line-length-limit

Answer (score 1):

As tinman said, there is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519738/source-line-length-limit) that might give you some info.

But consider this:

- Qt has been used in many lines of code so far (and counting). So, except if you have a **very** special case you should not have to worry about this problem. If you were referring  to a "long QLabel", you can still write code with line wraps and use the "+" operator.
- Also, if your code is written in such a way that even the compiler chokes, I would not want to read or maintain your code ;)

Comment: You can't use the + operator on C-string literals...only at run-time if they have been put into a string class.  To break a string literal across lines just close the quote and open a new one on the next line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135841/c-multiline-string-literal

Comment: Well, QString has the + and << operator overwritten... and yes, you can use a plain string literal too :)

Comment: Right, QString has the operators...my only point is that if you're trying to pass a string literal as a parameter to something that takes a QString then in order to get that append you'd have to generate the object at runtime.  So you'd end up writing `QString("first half of long string ") + QString("second half of long string")`. If you just do `QString("first half of long string " "second half of long string")` you can still break the line up between the constants *but* not pay for the append at runtime...the compiler puts all the characters in a row like a long constant would be.

Comment: so is this okay: QString("first half of long string "\n "second half of long string") ?   from "\n" I meant entering and writing the second string between quotes in a new line!

Comment: @Novin: Yup, as HostileFork mentioned. This is "more efficient" since it will be handled by the compiler as one string (compile time).